# Como puedo modificar una celda de mi Gridview asp.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp, webforms, gridview

**Estoy trabajando con una gridview que la lleno con un DataSourse, pero al llenarse la tabla tengo espacios vacíos.**

[image: imagen de mi tabla]

**será que hay alguna forma de llenar esos espacios con un cero?**

Espero y alguien pueda ayudarme :)

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué consulta de SQL estas usando  en el DataSourse?, desde la consulta puedes indicarle que si el valor es null ponga 0